# 'full-calendar' is not a known element

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

Hi I want to use fullcalendar in my project. I try to do everything according to the instructions as indicated on the documentation page for fullcalendar https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular

but I keep getting the same error:

```
ERROR in src/app/calendar/calendar.component.html:2:1 - error NG8001: 'full-calendar' is not a known element:
1. If 'full-calendar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'full-calendar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.


2 <full-calendar [options]="calendarOptions"></full-calendar>

src/app/home/hr/calendar/calendar.component.html:2:16 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'full-calendar'.
1. If 'full-calendar' is an Angular component and it has 'options' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'full-calendar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

2 <full-calendar [options]="calendarOptions"></full-calendar>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';  
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FullCalendarModule } from '@fullcalendar/angular'; // must go before plugins
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import { SharedModule } from '@app/shared/shared.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CalendarModule } from '@app/calendar/calendar.module';

FullCalendarModule.registerPlugins([
  dayGridPlugin,
  interactionPlugin,
  listPlugin,
  timeGridPlugin
]);

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FullCalendarModule,
    CalendarModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

calendar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CalendarOptions } from '@fullcalendar/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendar',
  templateUrl: './calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar.component.scss']
})
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {

  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    weekends: false,
    dateClick: this.handleDateClick.bind(this),
    events: [
      { title: 'event 1', date: '2019-04-01' },
      { title: 'event 2', date: '2019-04-02' }
    ]
  };

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  handleDateClick(arg: any) {
    alert('date click! ' + arg.dateStr);
  }

  toggleWeekends() {
    this.calendarOptions.weekends = !this.calendarOptions.weekends; // toggle the boolean!
  }

}
```

calendar.component.html

```
<button (click)="toggleWeekends()">toggle weekends</button>
<full-calendar [options]="calendarOptions"></full-calendar>
```

calendar.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CalendarRoutingModule } from './calendar-routing.module';
import { SharedModule } from '@app/shared/shared.module';
import { CalendarComponent } from '@app/home/hr/calendar/calendar.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CalendarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    CalendarRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class CalendarModule { }
```

In my angular.json I didn't make any changes.

Comment: Looks like your `CalendarComponent` is not part of your `AppModule`. Did you also import the `FullCalendarModule` in the module that declares the `CalendarComponent`?

Comment: yes, CalendarModule is imported into the AppModule

Comment: What is `CalendarModule`? Is it the module declaring your `CalendarComponent`? If yes, it does not matter if it is imported in your AppModule, it only matters that it imports the `FullCalendarModule`. So to be perfectly clear: the module listing `CalendarComponent` in its declarations needs to have `FullCalendarModule` in its imports. As you didn't add the code of this module I can't see if that's the case but I suppose that's your problem.

Comment: I added `calendar.module.ts`

Comment: So your problem is exactly what I wrote above. As I said, it needs to import `FullCalendarModule`.

Comment: you are right, the problem was solved by transferring imports and registering plugins FullCalendarModule from the app.module.ts to the calendar.module.ts. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You have to import `FullCalendarModule` in the modules where you use it (so inside CalendarModule in you example)!

Or create something like "SharedModule" and export your CalendarComponent from there. So you can import FullCalendarModule only in SharedModule but you have to import SharedModule where you want to use it.

You only have to choose the one way you prefer!